# How do I sort a vector of Strings alphabetically?

Tags: rust

I want to order a Strings vector alphabetically

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push("richard");
    vec.push("charles");
    vec.push("Peter");
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

I tried `println!("{:?}", vec.sort());` and `println!("{}", vec.sort_by(|a,b| b.cmp(a)));` and both response is `()`.

And I expect the following result

```
["charles", "Peter", "richard"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi I tried ```println!("{:?}", vec.sort());``` and ```println!("{}", vec.sort_by(|a,b| b.cmp(a)));``` and both response is ```()```

Comment: The response () is because the sort method modifies the vector itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SvetlinZarev , I'm new in Rust, the question can be very silly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort) function is defined on slices (and on `Vec`s, as they can `Deref` to slices) as `pub fn sort(&mut self)`, i.e. it performs sorting *in place*, mutating the existing piece of data. So to achieve what you're trying to do, you can try the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push("richard");
    vec.push("charles");
    vec.push("Peter");
    vec.sort();
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

Unhappily, this isn't quite the thing you want, since this [will sort "Peter" before "charles"](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd99ca1fb8ced6abc7c45329045ae256) - the default comparator of strings is case-sensitive (in fact, it's even locale-agnostic, since it [compares basing on Unicode code points](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-Ord)). So, if you want to perform case-insensitive sorting, [here's the modification](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=02f5da845c95cfb23e2e265069f34e60):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push("richard");
    vec.push("charles");
    vec.push("Peter");
    vec.sort_by(|a, b| a.to_lowercase().cmp(&b.to_lowercase()));
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

Comment: The line that does the sorting could be more concisely replaced by `vec.sort_by_key(|name| name.to_lowercase());`